# 422 : Unprocessable Entity when trying to publish maven repository using Sky-uk gradle-maven-plugin

Tags: android, maven-plugin, jitpack

I'm trying to create an android library using Jitpack. Now since the maven plugin in the docs is deprecated, I'm trying to use the one by sky-uk from [here](https://rubygems.registry.github.com/sky-uk/gradle-maven-plugin). But when I try to publish the repository, I get the following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':imagekit:publishMavenPublishPublicationToMavenRepository'.
> Failed to publish publication 'mavenPublish' to repository 'maven'
   > Could not write to resource 'https://github.com/****/*****.git/****/unspecified/*****-unspecified.aar'.
      > Could not PUT 'https://github.com/*******/*****.git/*******/unspecified/*******-unspecified.aar'. Received status code 422 from server: Unprocessable Entity
```

Comment: Do you find any solution to it? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: I got this error when my `artifactId` wasn't all lowercase. Reference https://github.community/t/gradle-maven-deploy-failing-with-422-unprocessable-entity/137299/3